# Radian measure in sin in R?

Tags: r, trigonometry

I want to calculate the following in R:

sin(52.517°)

and this should be equal to 0.79353. But when I code

```
sin(52.517)
```

I get

```
0.777119
```

So how can I get the 0.79353. I am not good in math, but I know something is not working with degrees and the radian measure here in R.

Comment: 1 degree =0.0174532925 radians ,sin(52.517*0.0174532925)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it works

```
1 degree =0.0174532925 radians
sin(52.517*0.0174532925)
[1] 0.7935339
```

**EDIT**

refered from [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-function-to-convert-degrees-to-radians/)

```
 degrees.to.radians<-function(degrees=45,minutes=30)
{
if(!is.numeric(minutes)) stop("Please enter a numeric value for minutes!\n")
if(!is.numeric(degrees)) stop("Please enter a numeric value for degrees!\n")
decimal<-minutes/60
c.num<-degrees+decimal
radians<-c.num*pi/180
radians
}
sin(degrees.to.radians(52.517,0))
[1] 0.7935339
```

Answer (score 18):

From the help page on `sin` which you can read by typing in `?sin` in the R console:

> Angles are in radians, not degrees (i.e., a right angle is π/2).

So by default, *the trigonometric functions take radians as input and not degrees*. To get the `sin(52.517)` you need to convert those degrees to a radian measure first:

```
52.517 degrees = 52.517 * (pi/180) = sin(52.517*(pi/180)) = 0.916...
```

If you do:

```
sin(52.517*(pi/180))
```

you get the wanted 0.7935339.

Comment: technically you don't need the brackets around `pi/180` ;)

Comment: I don't understand how you got 0.916... on the first snippet.

Answer (score 2):

well, let's just function things up

```
coss <- function(a){
  a=cos(a*pi/180)
  return(a)
}
sinn <- function(a){
  a= sin(a*pi/180)
  return(a)
}
tann <- function(a){
  a= tan(a*pi/180)
  return(a)
}
```